# Android RecyclerView item with multiple CheckBoxes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am going to create a `RecyclerView`. Each `RecyclerView` item has 5 dates, and each date should have a checkBox for whether the user should be notified on the date or not.

Should the model class consist of 5 boolean values for every date? or is there a better way to achieve this?

Example:

```
private Date date1, date2, date3, date4, date5;

private boolean notifyUserDate1, notifyUserDate2, notifyUserDate3, notifyUserDate4, notifyUserDate5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to extend the `Date` class like this:

```
class NotifiableDate extends Date {
   boolean notifyUser;
   ...

}
```

and then put five `NotifiableDate`s in your model class.